# CSS: Remove padding within select element

Tags: css, select, padding

I'm trying to remove padding from within a select element so that the text within it lines up with the text in the input element directly below it.

I've tried the below amongst other things.

```
select{
    padding-left:0;
    }
```

Any ideas?

JSfiddle here 
http://jsfiddle.net/pLSkH/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove the `text-indent: 3px;` from select css

```
input, select {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pLSkH/4/

`text-indent: 3px;`causing horizontal spacing with respect to the left, so its seems like a `padding`

Comment: Whoops, yeah. The select boxes render strangely in Dreamweaver with text-indent: 0;. Looks good in JSFiddle though.

Comment: Actually, this is not the solution, there still is a padding to the select box, the text in the input is not the same in the selectbox even after the text-indent is 0.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the padding issue (I wanted to remove the left "padding") in Chrome and Firefox by using a negative value:

style=text-indent:-3px;

Comment: Working for me only in FF, Chrome does not have any padding to the left and so this introduce another issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of left margin in select element-

```
select {
    margin-left: -6px;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

your jsfiddle had some minor html errors:

- you're not supposed to wrap a label around both the label and input.

it's supposed to be:

```
<label for "Firstnameame">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="Firstname">
```

when i corrected the html, a lot of the css changed. You can check out how mine came out and see if that was what you were looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/pLSkH/3/

Comment: It's fine/valid/good to wrap the input in a label. In this case there is no need for the label's `for` attribute.

Comment: w3c says it's ok to use it in that manner - apparently it's called a labeled control. Thanks @Moob for the tip re: 'for' attribute

Comment: ohh i see. oops! please ignore me then!

Comment: @BriceLin You're able to delete your answer if you like, and don't worry, I thought the same thing as you, so I too learnt something today :D

Comment: @MackieeE at least somebody else learned something as well, haha. i decided to leave it on so others who don't know as well would know.